# Django throws OperationalError : index row requires 35424 bytes, maximum size is 8191

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model

```
class Question(models.Model):
number = models.IntegerField(default=1)
question = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
exam = models.ForeignKey(
    "Exam",
    related_name="questions",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
marks = models.IntegerField(default=1)

audio = models.FileField(
    upload_to='audios/',
    blank = True,
    null = True
)

class Meta:
    unique_together = [
        # no duplicated number per exam
        ("exam","question", "number"), 
    ]
    ordering = ("number",)


def __str__(self):
    return self.exam.name+ '-'+ self.question
```

I want to save questions using this model. I have used a rich text editor for the question field and base64 encoded audio for the audio field. Whenever I try to add a new instance with a large rich text (i.e contains image) Django throws an exception saying index row requires 35424 bytes, maximum size is 8191\n",.

I even tried to upload a new instance from django admin panel and the error it gave is:

```
OperationalError at /admin/exam/question/14/change/

index row requires 35424 bytes, maximum size is 8191

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9025/admin/exam/question/14/change/
Django Version:     3.0.1
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    index row requires 35424 bytes, maximum size is 8191

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 86
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     3.7.6
Python Path:    

['/backend','/usr/local/lib/python37.zip','/usr/local/lib/python3.7','/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload','/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 13 Feb 2020 15:07:35 +0000
```

Comment: I have even tried to check the postgresql indexes for this table
`Indexes:
    "exam_question_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "exam_question_exam_id_question_number_8c9f82c0_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (exam_id, question, number)
    "exam_question_exam_id_e32fc5a5" btree (exam_id)
`

Comment: I have got  the traceback at
http://dpaste.com/2YPX0P5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using PostgreSQL and you rached the index size limit. You can read some discussion [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/25511356.post@talk.nabble.com). Note from [here](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html):

> The USING GIST clause tells PostgreSQL to use the generic index structure (GIST) when building the index. If you receive an error that looks like ERROR: index row requires 11340 bytes, maximum size is 8191 when creating your index, you have likely neglected to add the USING GIST clause.

This happens because you added multiple index on three fields where on of them is the `question`:

```
unique_together = [
    # no duplicated number per exam
    ("exam","question", "number"), 
]
```

You may want to use [PostgreSQL-specific](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/) index instead of default one or what's even better - reconsider if you need fields with this configuration in `unique_together`

Comment: I removed the question field from unique_together and it's working like a charm. Thank you.